# Can I know if the screen has been refreshed?

Tags: flutter

I plan to use the `navigator.pop` feature to move to the screen before.
Can I know if the screen has been moved to `navigator.pop?`
I don't want to use a method to pass variables to `navigator.pop`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the previous page using **`navigator.pop`**, you can use this library [`GetX`](https://pub.dev/packages/get) to move to the other page, and when you execute **`navigator.pop`**, you can **refresh** the page as shown by the following `code`:

```
Get.to(SecondPage()).then((value) => onGoBack());
```

When calling **`navigator.pop`**, `onGoBack()` is executed.

```
import 'dart:async';

 FutureOr onGoBack() {
    setState(() {});
  }
```